# Object properties depending on the value of a field

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm creating a JSON schema for a file that could look like this:

```
{
  "name": "My project",
  "debug": {
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "type 1",
        "options": {
          "option 1 for type 1": "my-project",
          "option 2 for type 1": "whatever"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "type 2",
        "options": {
          "option 1 for type 2": "my-project",
          "option 2 for type 2": "whatever",
          "option 3 for type 2": "whoohooo"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So basically, the "actions" can contain object that all have a "type" property and based on the value of this property, the options should display specific options. In summary, I'd like to be able to do some kind of mapping like:

```
"type 1": "#/definitions/type1Options",
"type 2": "#/definitions/type2Options"
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply a schema based on the value of a field using implication.  Start with twos schemas.  Let's call them A and B.  Schema A validates to true if the the field is the required value (Example: type is type 1).  Schema B is what should validate to true if the first schema is true (Example: has specific options).

With those two schemas you can create a statement to conditionally apply schema B based on schema A.  Either A does not validate to true or B validates to true.  This is called implication.

The schema gets a little complicated, but it works.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": { "enum": ["type 1", "type 2"] },
    "options": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "option 1 for type 1": { "type": "string" },
        "option 2 for type 1": { "type": "string" },
        "option 1 for type 2": { "type": "string" },
        "option 2 for type 2": { "type": "string" },
        "option 3 for type 2": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-1" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-2" }
  ],
  "definitions" {
    "type-1": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-is-type-1" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-1-options" }
      ]
    },
    "type-2": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-is-type-2" } },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/type-2-options" }
      ]
    },
    "type-is-type-1": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": ["type 1"] }
      }
    },
    "type-is-type-2": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": ["type 2"] }
      }
    },
    "type-1-options": {
      "properties": {
        "options": {
          "required": ["option 1 for type 1", "option 2 for type 1"]
        }
      }
    },
    "type-2-options": {
      "properties": {
        "options": {
          "required": ["option 1 for type 2", "option 2 for type 2", "option 3 for type 2"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I will test this as soon as I can but I have to add something to my question. "Type 1" and "type 2" were just examples. Actually, I can have more than 2 options here, possibly 20-30... is that solution still applicable ?

Comment: Yes, it will work for any number of options.  Just define more implications and add them to the `allOf`.

Comment: Hi, I just tested this but this does not produce the desired effect. All options appears in the auto-completition but and they all are required now. Here is what I have: https://pastebin.com/Hcr6LTDK (The "z" at the beginning is just a copy/paste issue ^^)

Comment: I put your schema into a validator and things seem to be validating properly.  Options are only required when they should be.  Possibly there is an issue with your validator?